# How to set all column types and measures simultaneously in SPSS?

Tags: statistics

I have over 150 different variables in my data set that when imported from a CSV file are assigned the incorrect type and measure. All data should be considered to be of type numeric and measure scale. The CSV files are dynamically generated and must remain so.

In SPSS' variable view, is it possible to set the type of all variables simultaneously? Also, it is possible to do the same with the measure of all variables?

Using some pre-processing, I am tempted to generate over 30000 columns but do not want to be going through each variable to make sure its type and measure are set correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since all the data was numeric, rounding to X number of decimal places allowed SPSS to correctly guess the correct type of the data it was being given. Some precision was sacrificed, but it made working with the generated CSV file much more enjoyable. The problem was easily solved with [a simple function](https://bitbucket.org/stephen-paul-chappell/predict-gold/src/ddf26e71fca5a2edd28440774b4349b1930a7d45/transformer.py?fileviewer=file-view-default#transformer.py-166).